# Paginate get related post by author function

Tags: pagination, get-posts

Is it possible to get this function paged? I've tried to add previous and next links but i'ts not working...

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
            global $authordata, $post;

            $authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post_type' => 'kenniscentrum', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );

            $output = '<ul>';
            foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
                $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>' . apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $authors_post->post_excerpt, $authors_post->ID ) . '</li>';
            }
            $output .= '</ul>';
      // bof previous and next links adde by me not working
            $output .= '<div class="nav-previous"> '.next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ) ) .'</div>';
            $output .= '<div class="nav-next"> '.previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) .'</div>';
     // eof previous and next links adde by me not working
            return $output;

        }

        /*add this hook where you need the related posts*/
        if(get_related_author_posts()) :
            echo get_related_author_posts();
        else :    
            echo 'No articles...';
        endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a function to place on functions.php, I find a workaround that can be placed on a template file:

```
<?php  
global $authordata, $post;
 query_posts( array( 
'author' => $authordata->ID, 
'post_type' => 'post', 
'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 
'paged'         => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 5 ));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
              <div id="nav-below" class="navigation">
              <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
              </div><!-- #nav-below -->
              <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: You must never use `query_posts`. For paginated custom queries, make use of `WP_Query`

Comment: @PieterGoosen How should I implement that? I took several hours making this work but I'm no expert... Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

As I already stated in a comment to [your answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172476/31545), you should never make use of [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

When you need paginated queries, [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) is the way to go as it returns all the necessary info for the correct calculations for pagination to work correctly. The other advantage here with using `WP_Query` is that results are cached making them a bit faster as well

You have to do two things here:

- Set the `paged` parameter in your query arguments
- Set the `$max_pages` parameter in [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)

You can try something like this: (*CAVEAT: This is untested*)

```
function get_related_author_posts() {

    global $authordata, $post;

    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 
        'author'            => $authordata->ID, 
        'post_type'         => 'kenniscentrum', 
        'post__not_in'      => array( $post->ID ), 
        'posts_per_page'    => 5,
        'paged'             => $paged
    );
    $authors_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    $output = '';

    if( $authors_posts->have_posts() ) {

        $output = '<ul>';

        while( $authors_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $authors_posts->the_post();

            $output .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</li>';

        }

        $output .= '</ul>';

        $output .= '<div class="nav-previous"> '. get_next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts' ), $authors_posts->max_num_pages) .'</div>';
        $output .= '<div class="nav-next"> '. get_previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ) .'</div>';


        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    return $output;

}
```

Comment: Hi, this paginations links stoped work when I've puted my site on a live server. This code has been successfully tested on my localhost but when I pass the site to live server, the pagination crashes with wordpress permalinks set (/% postname% /) and only works with the default permalinks (? p = 123). Why is this happening?

Comment: Strange, I've tested this on my local install with pretty permalinks, works perfectly. Have you flushed your permalinks again. Flush your permalinks and reload your home page. I can't really see any other reason why this should fail. By crash, do you mean 404 error. I'm off to bed now, if the problem persist, post a new question, as this problem is not caused by my code but something else.

Comment: I also tested this on my local machine and it's working there, but I've posted the comment because I was thinking that if you have more experience than I in programming, maybe, you could have a glimpse on why this could possible happen. The problem is that it doesn't let me go to the second or third or any other pages (if they exist) but it doesn't show me any 404 page...

Comment: Are you trying to use this on a static front page?

Comment: No. This is a listing page (single-listing.php) and I have the page like this: first it shows (by order) the single listing content, the comments, your code (to list all posts by the author of that listing), and after that are all listings related to the current one. Hope that helps...

Comment: To be honest, I have never really tried paginating a single page like that. I'm not even sure if it will work. Have you tried replacing the paginated links in my code with `wp_pagenavi`. What still bothers me, why does it work on local install and not your production site. The only thing I can think of is regarding [this notice](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Notes)

Comment: Me too... In my local php.ini I have: mysql.trace_mode = Off and tried to turn it On by placing this: mysql.trace_mode = On. After that I've reset all services and the pagination on localhost has working, so I don't think that is the problem...

Comment: I think what you should do is, ask a new question and refer back to this question, stating all the details that might help someone to answer this issue. At this stage I really have no clue what can be the cause of this. Like I said, I have never tried paginating a single page like this. It is worth no while going forth and back like this grasping at air

Comment: here is [new one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172825/related-posts-by-author-pagination-not-working-on-the-production-site) , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code after `global $authordata, $post;` add

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

and change your code from

```
$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post_type' => 'kenniscentrum', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) );
```

to

```
$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 
    'author' => $authordata->ID, 
    'post_type' => 'kenniscentrum', 
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 5 ) 
);
```

Your function should work properly with the paged now.

Comment: I already tried this before but your code doesn't works also. This is driving me nuts....