# pagination redirecting from page number url before page requested

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, single

I have a CPT called staff. On their single-staff.php pages i have a list of items they are related to. This has become too long so now we want pagination. I can create the page links fine but it redirects itself to a URL without the /page/number.

http://wonkhedev.jynk.net/staff/mark-leach/ main page

http://wonkhedev.jynk.net/staff/mark-leach/page/2/ page 2 link but gets directed back to 
http://wonkhedev.jynk.net/staff/mark-leach/

```
//in functions.php
function get_author_articles($id){

  // backwards finds CPT 'blogs' this staff member is related to.
  $meta_query = array(
    'paged' =>  get_query_var('paged'),
    'post_type' => 'blogs',
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'blog_author', // name of custom field, ACF
        'value' => '"' . $id . '"',  // CPT 'staff' id.
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
  );

  $author_articles = query_posts($meta_query);

  return $author_articles;

}
```

// in single-staff.php

```
$blog_articles = get_author_articles($post->ID);
$blog_articles_total = $wp_query->found_posts;    
<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
      <nav class="post-nav">
        <ul class="pager">
          <li class="previous"><?php next_posts_link(__('&larr; Older Articles', 'roots')); ?></li>
          <li class="next"><?php previous_posts_link(__('Newer Articles &rarr;', 'roots')); ?></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So you need to paginate the related products

Comment: Also note, `query_posts` breaks the main query object, so you will never get this working as you are setting the main query object to your custom query. **Never ever** do that, you should really really avoid using `query_posts`

Comment: isn't hat what this does -  'paged' =>  get_query_var('paged') and 'posts_per_page' => 20 ?  The main object is finished with so that doesn't matter. The main issue is the URL redirect.

Comment: That will not work, `query_posts` stuffs pagination, also, single pages, just as static front pages, uses `page` as query var, not `paged` as normal archive pages do

Comment: ok - so it doesn't work. Anything useful to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `query_post` as it breaks the main query object and resets it to the current custom query. This breaks plugins and custom functionalities like related posts and pagination. I have done an [extensive answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191934/31545) on that, so be sure to check it out, as well as the [answer by @Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/31545).

It should also be noted, single pages, just as static front pages uses `page` and not `paged` as normal archive pages and pages do

Lets first look at your related posts function:

### RELATED POSTS

We would first want to properly code the function to allow for it to be safe and dynamic. I accept that `$id` should be the single post ID of the post you are viewing, so with that in mind, lets code the function:

Just a few notes before we do:

- The code is commented, so it will be easy to follow
- The code requires PHP 5.4 +
- Modify the code as needed

Here is the code

```
/**
 * Function to return realted posts_per_page
 *
 * @param (array) $args Compatible argumnets to pass to WP_Query
 * @return $author_articles
 */
function get_author_articles( $args = [] )
{
    // First make sure we are on a single page, else return false
    if ( !is_single() )
        return false;

    // Get the single post object we are on
    $current_post = get_queried_object();

    // Set our $page variable
    $page = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 0;

    // backwards finds CPT 'blogs' this staff member is related to.
    $meta_query_defaults = [
        'post__not_in'   => $current_post->ID, // Excludes the current post
        'paged'          => $page,
        'post_type'      => $current_post->post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'meta_query'     => [
            [
                'key'     => 'blog_author', // name of custom field, ACF
                'value'   => $current_post->ID,  // CPT 'staff' id.
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ]
        ],
    ];

    // Add our custom arguments to the $meta_query_defaults array
    if (    $args
         && is_array( $args )
    ) {
        $meta_query_defaults = wp_parse_args(  $args, $meta_query_defaults );
    }

    $author_articles = new WP_Query( $meta_query_defaults );

    return $author_articles;
}
```

You can pass, as first parameter, an array of parameters that is valid for `WP_Query` to adjust and modify the default parameters in the function which is passed to `WP_Query`

### PAGINATION

As I have stated, single post pages and static front pages uses `page` and not `paged`. In order to make pagination work, you would require a complete custom function. I have done such a function a while ago, which you can check [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172900/31545).

Here is slightly modified versions

```
function get_single_pagination_link( $pagenum = 1 ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    if(    !is_single() 
        || !$wp_rewrite->permalink_structure 
    )
        return false;

    $pagenum = (int) $pagenum;

    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $request = get_permalink( $post_id );

    if ( $pagenum > 1 )
        $request = trailingslashit( $request ) . user_trailingslashit( $pagenum );
   return esc_url( $request );
}

function get_next_single_page_link ( $label = null, $max_page = 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if( !is_single() ) 
        return false;

    if ( !$max_page ) {
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    }

    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

    $next_page = intval($paged) + 1;

    if ( null === $label ) {
        $label = __( 'Next Page &raquo;' );
    }

    if ( ( $next_page <= $max_page ) ) {
        return '<a href="' . get_single_pagination_link( $next_page ) . '">' . $label . '</a>';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function get_previous_single_page_link( $label = null ) {

    if( !is_single() ) 
        return false; 

    $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

    $prev_page = intval($paged) - 1;

    if ( null === $label ) {
        $label = __( '&laquo; Previous Page' );
    }

    if ( ( $prev_page > 0 ) ) {
        return '<a href="' . get_single_pagination_link( $prev_page ) . '">' . $label . '</a>';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### BASIC USAGE

You can now use it as follow

```
$q = get_author_articles();
if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        // Add your markup, etc.

    }
    echo get_previous_single_page_link();
    echo get_next_single_page_link( null , $q->max_num_pages );

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Pieter - thank you so much. I was getting bogged down with rewrite rules and using trailingslashit bypassed that completely. NB. i had to tweak query_defaults to set the CPT - 'post_type'      => 'blogs'. Noted the use of  new WP_Query and reading up on that a bit now. D.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. As I said, you should adjust and modify my code as you see fit to fit your exact needs. Good luck further on your project. ;-)