# Make a custom loop inside single.php with pagination

Tags: loop, pagination

I want to create a custom loop inside a `single-ediciones.php` file and I need pagination (actually AJAX pagination).

I need my normal loop because I need to show some data of the CPT "Ediciones" and I want a custom loop to show some CPT related to the current CPT via ID.

Actually, I don't know if is possible have a normal loop and inside a custom loop with pagination.

Right now I can get the `"ALL_THE_URL/page/2"` work, but without pagination. Even using `new WP_Query` and adding the `get_next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );`.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) :
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $edicion_ID = get_the_ID();
        $edicion_titulo = get_the_title();
        $edicion_titulo = strtolower($edicion_titulo); ?>
        <div class="container ediciones-detalle-contenedor">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8">
                    <h3><?php echo $edicion_titulo; ?></h3>
               </div>

               <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4 col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">
                   <div class="row">
                        <?php 
                        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                        $args = array(
                            'numberposts'   => 4,
                            'post_type'     => array('temas', 'perfiles', 'udem-mundo', 'deportes', 'cultura'),
                            'meta_query'    => array(
                                'relation'      => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'contenido_relacionado_impreso',
                                    'value'     => 'si',
                                    'compare'   => '=',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'       => 'contenido_relacionado_edicion',
                                    'value'     => $edicion_ID,
                                    'compare'   => '=',
                                ),
                            ),
                            'paged'         => $paged,
                        );

                        $posts_relacionados_edicion = get_posts($args);
                        if ( !empty($posts_relacionados_edicion) ) :
                            foreach ($posts_relacionados_edicion as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-titulo-chico"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach;
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I far I know, `get_posts()` function can not be used to paginated results. It is intended to get an array of posts and [it sets `no_found_rows` to `true` by default from WP 3.1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14528). Pagination won't work unless you set it to false, or better, use WP_Query.

`numberposts` is also a invalid argument.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'post_type'       => array('temas', 'perfiles', 'udem-mundo', 'deportes', 'cultura'),
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
         array(
            'key'       => 'contenido_relacionado_impreso',
            'value'     => 'si',
            'compare'   => '=',
         ),
         array(
             'key'       => 'contenido_relacionado_edicion',
             'value'     => $edicion_ID,
             'compare'   => '=',
         ),
     ),
     'paged'         => $paged,
 );

 $posts_relacionados_edicion = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $posts_relacionados_edicion->have_posts() ) :

     while( $posts_relacionados_edicion->have_posts() ) :

         $posts_relacionados_edicion->the_post(); ?>

         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-titulo-chico"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
              </div>

      <?php endwhile;

      echo paginate_links( array(
          'current' => $paged,
          'total' => $posts_relacionados_edicion->max_num_pages,
          'format' => '?page=%#%'
      ) );

       wp_reset_postdata();

  else : ?>

     <?php _e( 'No found posts.', 'textdomain' ); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

The code above generates paginate links in the format `example.com/{post-name}/{page-number}` and it seems to be working.

The next code generates paginate links in the format `example.com/{post-name}/page/{page-number}`, but they are redirect to `example.com/{post-name}/` and makes pagination not working. More work and test would be needed if you want to use URLs like `example.com/{post-name}/page/{page-number}`:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'post_type'       => array('temas', 'perfiles', 'udem-mundo', 'deportes', 'cultura'),
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
         array(
            'key'       => 'contenido_relacionado_impreso',
            'value'     => 'si',
            'compare'   => '=',
         ),
         array(
             'key'       => 'contenido_relacionado_edicion',
             'value'     => $edicion_ID,
             'compare'   => '=',
         ),
     ),
     'paged'         => $paged,
 );

 $posts_relacionados_edicion = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $posts_relacionados_edicion->have_posts() ) :

     while( $posts_relacionados_edicion->have_posts() ) :

         $posts_relacionados_edicion->the_post(); ?>

         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-titulo-chico"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
              </div>

      <?php endwhile;

      echo paginate_links( array(
          'current' => $paged,
          'total' => $posts_relacionados_edicion->max_num_pages
      ) );

       wp_reset_postdata();

  else : ?>

     <?php _e( 'No found posts.', 'textdomain' ); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Or you could also build your own pagination endpoint:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'my_page' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'my_page' ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'post_type'       => array('post'),
    'paged'         => $paged,
 );

 $posts_relacionados_edicion = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $posts_relacionados_edicion->have_posts() ) :

     while( $posts_relacionados_edicion->have_posts() ) :

         $posts_relacionados_edicion->the_post(); ?>

         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-titulo-chico"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
              </div>

      <?php endwhile;

      echo paginate_links( array(
          'current' => $paged,
          'total' =>  $posts_relacionados_edicion->max_num_pages,
          'format' => '?my_page=%#%'
      ) );

       wp_reset_postdata();

  else : ?>

     <?php _e( 'No found posts.', 'textdomain' ); ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
```

Combined with the rewrite tag:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_tag( 'my_page', '([0-9]+)' );
} );
```

Comment: This will not work unfortunately, `numberposts` is invalid in `WP_Query`, `WP_Query` only accepts `posts_per_page` and `showposts` (*which is not depreciated as the codex incorrectly states*). Secondly, single post pages (*just like static front pages*)  uses the  `page` query var, and not `paged` like other pages/archives. My [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172900/31545) might also be useful in answering the question

Comment: Opps, I just copied `numberposts` that from the question. Thanks Pieter. As far I understand, `page` query var is used for single post pagination; not for pagination of a loop, not matter if the loop is in a single template. Let me do some tests.